# "Smearing" a function with a gaussian

Tags: functions

Let's say I have a function that represents how much light is produced within a particular volume:

```
gamma[t_] := Piecewise[{{0.2 Exp[-t/13] + 0.5 Exp[-t/35] + 0.3 Exp[-t/270],  t >= 0}}, 0]
```

And let's say that the light is collected at one end of this volume, and the arrival time is gaussian distributed for a particular source time (i.e. if we isolate all of the light emitted at `t`, then it will arrive in a gaussian distribution centered around `t'` with a particular standard deviation).

Thus far I have come up with this:

```
gaussian[t_, μ_, σ_] := 1/(σ Sqrt[2 Pi]) Exp[-(1/2) ((t - μ)/σ)^2]

SetAttributes[gaussianSmear, HoldAll]

gaussianSmear[t_, f_[a___, y_, b___], σ_] := NIntegrate[ 
  f[a, y, b] gaussian[t, y, σ], {y, t-6σ, t+6σ}]
```

This will work, but it is very slow.  Is there a faster way to perform this?  Or is there a built-in function of some kind?  I'm aware of the function `GaussianFilter`, but it only seems to operate on discrete data, not an arbitrary function.

An example usage, original function:

```
gamma[t_] := Piecewise[{{0.2 Exp[-t/13] + 0.5 Exp[-t/35] + 0.3 Exp[-t/270],  t >= 0}}, 0]
neutron[t_] := Piecewise[{{0.2 Exp[-t/13] + 0.5 Exp[-t/59] + 0.3 Exp[-t/490], t >= 0}}, 0]
Plot[{gamma[t], neutron[t]}, {t, 0, 80}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"gamma", "neutron"}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Theoretical activity of crystal", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (ns)", "Output level"}]
```

[image]

An example usage, after smearing:

```
Plot[{gaussianSmear[t, gamma[y], 1], 
  gaussianSmear[t, neutron[y], 1]}, {t, -2, 80}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"gamma", "neutron"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Light collected by SiPM", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (ns)", "Output level"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `x` is not defined. An example of how to use `gaussianSmear` would be nice also.

Comment: Sorry, I changed variables from x to t when translating this from my notebook in order to make my intentions more clear, and I missed an instance.

Comment: Examples added.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a bit embarrassing.

I just realized that what I was performing was essentially a convolution of my original wave form with a standard Gaussian with a mean of 0.

So in other words, I can simply write:

```
Convolve[gamma[t], gaussian[t, 0, 1], t, y]
```

To get a function that can be directly plotted and manipulated much faster than my `NIntegrate` monstrosity.